# In Halacha, can you sue for Alienation of Affection?

Tags: halacha, marriage, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court, divorce

In old times, there were laws on the books that defined a cause of action called "[Alienation of Affections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienation_of_affections)" which, among other things, allowed an aggrieved spouse to sue their spouse's illicit lover. One US state (North Carolina) still has AOA laws on the books and there are still cases brought on these grounds

Is there a similar concept in Judaism? Obviously in Judaism, adultery is a criminal matter, but suppose someone outside the marriage committed an emotional adultery or otherwise turned spouses against one another, destroying their marriage but without any physical transgression. Are there legal remedies in Halacha?

Comment: Considering a man can take a second wife (we don't do this today but that's a separate issue), it seems unlikely this concept exists in halacha

Comment: @יהושעק why would that make a difference? Even if you have 10 wives, you still would probably not want to be "stolen" away

Comment: @lgshost the point being that a woman has no right to her husband's exclusive attention. Although it's highly recommended that a husband get his wife's agreement before taking another wife, I'm not sure that he has to.

Comment: @Esther but a husband has a right to his wife's exclusive attention. Can he sue if another man takes it?